# Can you perform stochastic simulations on a quantum computer?

Tags: quantum-state

In the article [*"Biasing the quantum vacuum to control macroscopic probability distributions"*](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/37440648/)[[arXiv:2303.03455](https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.03455)],
authors present what they call a "p-bit" i.e., a probabilistic bit. It is a photon whose
probability for its phase to be $0$ or $\pi$ can be controlled.

In short, authors foresee
that this would be the cornerstone for a Probabilistic Power Unit which could
handle stochastic simulations much better than CPU, because (it is unclear actually to understand how) the p-bits would stand for the probability laws involved in stochastic simulations, instead of being compelled to perform Monte Carlo simulations on a CPU.

**Which leads to my question, can QPU perform stochastic simulations in a smarter way than a CPU ?**

To my opinion, this would mean to encode probability laws directly on qubit registers.

As an example, say a stochastic variable $X$ which can take real values $x_1,\dots,x_N$ with
probabilities $P(X=x_i)=p_i$ :
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\sum_{i=1}^n p_i=1
\end{equation}

Assume we have several qubits $q_1,\dots,q_n$ such that $2^n = N$. The register is
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
|q_1\dots q_n\rangle = a_1|0\dots 0\rangle + a_2|0\dots 01\rangle + \dots + a_N|1\dots 1\rangle
\end{equation}

The first problem I see is that the norm corresponding to (1) is the norm1 (absolute value)
whereas the function state (2) is normalized with respect to the Hilbert space norm.